# Why cellForRowAtIndex doesn't run at all?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've added TableView to my controller and created custom UITableViewCell. Later, I've tried to run this code:

```
func tableView(educationTableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> educationCell {
    let cell:educationCell = educationTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! educationCell

    print("TableView runs")

    return cell
}
```

but I do not get my print in logs `TableView runs`. I do not understand what happens and why it doesn't run. Who knows, why this problem appears?

I read other answers in SO, but noone helps =/

Comment: Did you set the table view's `dataSource` property to point to your view controller?

Comment: yes, of course I did @NicolasMiari

Comment: May be numberOfrows method returns 0.

Comment: Did you also implement `func tableView(... numberOfRowsInSection ...)` and return a value greater than 0?

Comment: Is the table setup in a storyboard? Does it have dynamic cells, or static?

Comment: @MidhunMP OMG! Yes, it returns 0! I get json in ViewWillAppear and fill my array, later I take `numberOfRowsInSection return myArray.count`. Asynchronous problem, I seem

Comment: @NicolasMiari read the comment above, please

Comment: Try calling `tableView.reloadData()` once, **after** obtaining your array. That triggers a call for `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`, for the visible rows (I think).

Comment: Okay! I've fixed it! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

need the return value of numberOfRowsInSection greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have implemented proper **DataSource and Delegate** for controller, **number of rows is greater then 0**

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! //hook this to your storyboard tableview

    // MARK: - Controller life cycle stack
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //confirm table's delegate and data source programmatically
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;

    }

    //table view delegate and data source methods
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        //number of rows must be greater then 0 to get called "CellForRowAtIndex"
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CraditCardCell
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        print("You selected cell");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that if he didn't, the compiler wouldn't let him set the `dataSource` property to `self` (view controller).

Comment: ...Although I'm not sure if he could still hook it through Interface Builder without errors

Comment: @NicolasMiari agree, i have updated my answer to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be because you modified the return type to educationCell, instdead of the standard UITableViewCell. Try changing that.

Comment: In that case the cast would fail and the app would crash, wouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did use cast in some of my apps, but I don't recall changing the return type of the function. I don't have my code in front of me, but I'll double check later on.

Comment: Typically, you dequeue your cells with a specific identifier, that is associated with a specific `UITableViewCell` subclass (either by setting identifier in Storyboard, or by calling the `register...` methods programmatically). So, right after dequeuing, you force-cast to the appropriate subclass (because it should be safe).

Comment: The alternative to force-casting would be to do an `if let...`, if you fear the cast could fail, but you still have to return _something_ in the `else` case (because the method expects you to return a non-optional `UITableViewCell`), so if you are over-defensive you could return `UITableViewCell()` to satidfy the compiler.... not very elegant.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I just checked on the Apple developer library (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1), where they create an example app. The `tableView` method returns a `UITableViewCell`, but after dequeuing it force cast it to the subclass. My memory works sometimes!

Comment: As long as the reuse identifier is setup correctly in the storyboard, of course, and the cell in the tableview has been associated with the right class.